# WebClient get issue TimeoutException while I've set the timeout

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 20000ms in 'source(MonoDefer)' (and no fallback has been configured)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.handleTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:289) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.doTimeout(FluxTimeout.java:274) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutTimeoutSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:396) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.StrictSubscriber.onNext(StrictSubscriber.java:89) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:73) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDelay$MonoDelayRunnable.run(MonoDelay.java:117) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) [reactor-core-3.3.3.RELEASE.jar:3.3.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Use dependency:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

This is my code:

````
getWebClient = WebClient.builder()
               .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
               .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> { 
                    lientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(
                            objectMapper, new MimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
                })
                .build();```
````

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
 WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(ExchangeStrategies
             .builder()
                .codecs(codecConfigurer -> codecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(-1)).build())
                .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection()).compress(true).keepAlive(true)))
                .codecs(clientCodecConfigurer -> clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(
                        objectMapper, new MimeType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))))
                .build();
```